# How to change the Linux kernel swap daemon (kswapd) timeout?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, swap, virtual-memory

I want to reduce the kswapd timeout to increase the performance by use of fast devices like Flash, SSD as swapping devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the behavior of `kswapd` through 2 ways

### Through Proc File System

From [IBM Developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-adfly/index.html),

> **/proc/sys/vm/kswapd**
>
> 1. Maximum number of pages the kernel tries to free at one time. If you want to increase bandwidth to/from swap, you will need to increase
>      this number.
> 2. Minimum number of times the kernel tries to free a page on each swap.
> 3. The number of pages the kernel can write in one swap. This has the greatest impact on system performance. The larger the value, the more
>      data can be swapped and the less time is spent disk seeking. However,
>      a value that is too large will adversely affect system performance by
>      flooding the request queue

### Through Kernel Code

[kswapd( void *p )](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/vmscan.c#L2996) calls [kswapd_try_to_sleep()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/vmscan.c#L2939). [Here is where](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/vmscan.c#L2951) the `kswapd` daemon tries to sleep. Like this-

```
schedule_timeout(HZ/10) /* You need to modify here to change the timeout value */
```

Actually this is a very short time period for which it sleeps. After this short sleep, it checks if it was a premature sleep. If not, it goes fully to sleep ( no timeout here ) until explicitly woken up.

Tweaking the kernel code, building and testing it is no easy task. So I suggest you go the `/proc` filesystem way!

Comment: `/proc/sys/vm/kswapd` doesn't exist on my machine using Linux 4.0 or 3.14.