# The timing to start Android Low Memory killer

Tags: android

As we know, low memory killer starts at a fixed time. How long is the "fixed time"? Where is the code to configure this?

Comment: your question is not clear. can add some extra info in your question.

Answer (score 11):

Android LMK doesn't start freeing memory at some particular time, but it depends on minfree values:

```
 /sys/module/lowmemorykiller/parameters/minfree
```

For example, if `cat  /sys/module/lowmemorykiller/parameters/minfree` has the following values:

```
1536,2048,4096,5120,5632,6144
```

Then that means these values are thresholds memory for starting killing of these particular kind of processes.

```
FOREGROUND_APP:1536 
VISIBLE_APP:2048
SECONDARY_SERVER:4096
HIDDEN_APP:5120
CONTENT_PROVIDER:5632
EMPTY_APP:6144
```

E.g., when free memory (RAM) in system is less than (6144*4/1024)= 24 MB, then LMK will start killing `EMPTY_APP` processes. Similarly if still memory condition don't improve it will start killing process in `EMPTY_APP->CONTENT_PROVIDER->....->FOREGROUND_APP` (last to be killed, this should never happen).

Comment: i have a background sticky service active on screen (used SYSTEM_WINDOW_ALERT), LMK killed and started after 48s. Is there a way to set high priority? This service runs as a core app under /system/priv-app/

Comment: i think the better way to proceed will be to fix memory footprint of your service.....try checking how much memory its consuming...

Answer (score 0):

In the asynchronous case, LMK is timed by the kernel pageout daemon (kswapd). So I suppose you can dig a little deeper into kswapd control flow to figure out if it's wake up time is bounded which will provide a part answer to your question on **timing** constraints.

The LMK shrinker callback can also be invoked outside of the kswapd context. This occurs when the system performs a direct synchronous page reclaim (see. mm/page_alloc.c)

**Reference notes:**

1. http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/KernelAnalysis-HOWTO-7.html

**Related SO Questions/Answers**

1. [Q:how-to-change-the-linux-kernel-swap-daemon-kswapd-timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817737/how-to-change-the-linux-kernel-swap-daemon-kswapd-timeout)
2. [A:how-to-change-the-linux-kernel-swap-daemon-kswapd-timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9820354/624783)